# Add an extra field to BuddyPress activity form

Tags: buddypress

I want to add a custom text field in the **BuddyPress** activity form and save it. I can add it with this code:

```
add_action ( "bp_after_activity_post_form", 'my_test_function' );

function my_test_function(){
    echo '<div id="tags-content"> 
            <input type="text" name="tags" value="" />
        </div>';
}
```

How can I save it? I'm trying this, but it never goes to it.

```
add_action('bp_activity_after_save', 'where_activity_from', 10, 3);

function where_activity_from( $activity ) {
    echo "test";
    //die;
}
```

Comment: 3rd party plugin questions are off-topic, try https://buddypress.org/support/

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there is only 1 `$accepted_args`, not 3, so the `add_action` is:

```
add_action('bp_activity_after_save', 'where_activity_from', 10, 1);
```

Second, the value in your `tags` input is never parsed by `BP_Activity_Activity->save()` so how could it be part of the array available thru the hook?

Try using the `$_POST` array, like this:

```
add_action('bp_activity_after_save', 'where_activity_from', 10, 1);
function where_activity_from( $activity ) {
    // write_log( $_POST['tags'] );
    // do something with $_POST['tags']
}
```